# Pass Interface Dynamically as Parameter In Angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript

I am getting confused how to pass interface as parameter and set to http get ,post as globally

I written all http post, get, put, delete functions globally

```
  public get_api(path: string, Interface) {
    return this.http.get<Interface>(API_ENDPOINT + path);
  }
```

Now I want to pass interface from another .ts file

```
  this.http_global.get_api('user',Interface).subscribe(.....=>);
```

Can anyone helps !!!

Thanks In advance!!!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass it as a generic type parameter, just as `http.get` does:

```
public get_api<T>(path: string) {
  return this.http.get<T>(API_ENDPOINT + path);
}

this.http_global.get_api<Interface>('user').subscribe(.....=>);
```

If there is a clear relation between the string passed in an the result type, you might consider adding some overloads so the user doesn't have to specify the type all the type:

```
public get_api(path: 'user'): Observable<User>
public get_api<T>(path: string) : Observable<T>
public get_api<T>(path: string) : Observable<T> {
  return this.http.get<T>(API_ENDPOINT + path);
}

this.http_global.get_api<Interface>('other').subscribe(.....=>);
this.http_global.get_api<('user').subscribe(.....=>); // Observable<User>
```

Comment: @user3556287 don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful :)